# What is so important about gdbus and gdmain, that they are so frequently leaves in the process tree?

Tags: ps, d-bus

For a better understanding of Linux, I run `pstree` and looked-up the different services to understand what they are doing and which processes they are starting on their part.

While doing so, it is not possible to overlook that a lot of services, even unrelated ones, end in **{gdbus}** and **{gdmain}**, always as a couple.

What is so important about them, that makes them so ubiquitous?

Comment: They are [DBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) threads, and many applications end up using DBus (sometimes through libraries). Opinions on the "importance" of DBus are ... diverse.

Comment: how do those argue, who think it is not that important?